# Create a 1D array from the mode of elements in a 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Is there a numpy (or other) library that can do the equivalent of:

```
from statistics import multimode
labels = np.empty(shape=(len(indices)))
for index in range(len(indices)):
  # get the mode (may be several)
  modes = multimode(asLabels[index])
  labels[index] = modes[0] if len(modes) == 1 else maxLabel
```

I'm guessing that there is no shortcut to the above. But numpy is so powerful, I'm asking on the off chance there is.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample input (small) and expected output?

Comment: Do you want the single most common value in each row of `asLabels`?  If so why use `multimode` instead of `mode`?

Comment: I haven't used it, but the `mode` function in the `scipy.stats` module may do the job: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html#scipy.stats.mode

Comment: @hpaulj I use multimode because if there is a tie for mode values, then I use the most common label from the total dataset.